# Account Edit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to edit users account but when I loaded the view it does not display the users default account information.Below is my model view and controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have a database which includes includes all the users information. so I want to retrieve it and perform an update function.

**CONTROLLER**

```
/**
     * This function is used load user edit information
     * @param number $userId : Optional : This is user id
     */
    function editOld($userId = NULL)
    {
            if($userId == null)
            {
                redirect('pages/settings');
            }

            $data['userInfo'] = $this->settings_model->getUserInfo($userId);

            $data['title'] = 'Settings';

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/settings', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

    /**
     * This function is used to edit the user information
     */
    function editUser()
    {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $userId = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Full Name','trim|required|max_length[128]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean|max_length[128]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[3]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('birthday','Birthday','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','Gender','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile Number','required|min_length[9]|xss_clean');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->editOld($userId);
            }
            else
            {
                $name = $this->input->post('name');
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $bio = $this->input->post('bio');
                $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
                $birthday = $this->input->post('birthday');
                $gender = $this->input->post('gender');

                $userInfo = array();

                if(empty($password))
                {
                    $userInfo = array('email'=>$email, 'username'=>$username, 'name'=>$name,
                                    'mobile'=>$mobile, 'bio'=>$bio, 'birthday'=>$birthday, 'gender'=>$gender, 'updatedBy'=>$userId, 'updatedDtm'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                }
                else
                {
                    $userInfo = array('email'=>$email, 'username'=>$username, 'name'=>$name,
                                    'mobile'=>$mobile, 'bio'=>$bio, 'birthday'=>$birthday, 'gender'=>$gender, 'updatedBy'=>$userId, 'updatedDtm'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                }

                $result = $this->settings_model->editUser($userInfo, $userId);

                if($result == true)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Profile updated successfully');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Profile update failed');
                }

                redirect('pages/settings');
            }

    }
```

**MODEL**

```
function getUserInfo($userId)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, name, email, username, mobile, birthday, gender, bio');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('isDeleted', 0);
        $this->db->where('id', $userId);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }


    /**
     * This function is used to update the user information
     * @param array $userInfo : This is users updated information
     * @param number $userId : This is user id
     */
    function editUser($userInfo, $userId)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $userId);
        $this->db->update('users', $userInfo);

        return TRUE;
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php

$userId = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$mobile = '';
$username = '';
$birthday = '';
$bio = '';

if(!empty($userInfo))
{
    foreach ($userInfo as $uf)
    {
        $userId = $uf->id;
        $name = $uf->name;
        $email = $uf->email;
        $mobile = $uf->mobile;
        $username = $uf->username;
        $birthday = $uf->birthday;
        $bio = $uf->bio;
    }
}
?>

<form class="col s12" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>settings/editUser" method="post" id="editUseri" role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>" name="userId" id="userId" />
          <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="username" type="text" class="validate" data-length="15" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="box-footer">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
 </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass your details into session and use sessions to display it. remember to update the session .

```
value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>"
```

mark as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

`$this->db->last_query()`

to check what is the query going. I think it would needs to set the

```
$query->result();
```

`$this->db->set()` the data part for handling update query

Comment: where should I add that?

Comment: Just below the modal :





 function editUser($userInfo, $userId)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $userId);
        $this->db->update('users', $userInfo);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
         exit;
        return TRUE;
    }

Comment: `$query->result_array();` for what ? He want to only one row from database then why you need to use `result_array()` ?

Comment: Try to pass in the array format in where clause :
"$this->db->where(array('id'=>$userid);"
and let us know if working then mark accepted

Comment: what problem face it ??

Comment: Still doesnt display it. the update function works it is just the display of information on the screen that is not working

Comment: Are you able to update the code in codeignter . now what exactly you want more in this.

Answer (score 0):

try this only for debug your error
you not checked **user session** set or not

change from

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  $this->editOld($userId);
}else{
  ....
  ....
}
```

to

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  //your validation error
  echo "validation error";

}else if($userId){
  //if session set for user
  $this->editOld($userId);
}else{
  ....
  ....
}
```